nonlinear itemize/enumerate uncover
I have a sequece of items to uncover in the eitemize/enumerate/description list on one frame side and appropriate graphics on the other. At some points I want to zoom in or provide more graphics in sequence.
I can \item<m-n> / \uncover<n> it manually but I'd like to generate the sequence automatically and pause the automatic advancement for n steps ar given point.
something like
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item 1
  \item <foo 1> 2-3
  \item 4

\item 5
\end{itemize}
\uncover<1> A
\uncover<2> B
\uncover<3> C
\uncover<4> D
\uncover<5> E
\end{frame}
\end{document}

Rendering frame unfolding in sequence like this
1            --- A
1 / 2-3      --- B
1 / 2-3      --- C
1 / 2-3 / 4  --- D
1/2-3/ 4 / 5 --- E


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

You can add an additional overlay before the 4th item:
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item 1
  \item 2-3 
  \item<+(1)-> 4
\end{itemize}

\uncover<1>{a}

\uncover<2>{b}

\uncover<3>{c}

\uncover<4>{d}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

Alternatively, you could add a pause after the second item:
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item 1
  \item 2-3 \pause
  \item 4
  \item 5 
\end{itemize}
\onslide<1->

\uncover<1>{a}

\uncover<2>{b}

\uncover<3>{c}

\uncover<4>{d}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


it seems I need to add the counter shift command <+(1)-> everywhere following the shift. So this shift counter for one \item. I'd like to pause the advancement instead so I dont need to add fourth \item with the same shift but plain.
